# C#: A method parameter that implements a particular interface

Tags: c#, objective-c, .net, xamarin.ios

Let's say I have a class called `UIViewController`.

```
public class UIViewController
{
    // ... methods
}
```

And I have an interface `IDoFancyFlips`

```
public interface IDoFancyFlips
{
   // ... methods
}
```

I have a classes that extend `UIViewController` and implement the interface as follows.

```
public class FancyViewController : UIViewController, IDoFancyFlips
{
   // ... methods
}
```

Now I want to write a method that takes a `UIViewController` as a parameter, but only ones that implement `IDoFancyFlips`.

```
public void FlipAndShow(??? controller) {
    // implementation
}
```

My question is what do I put in the ???. I couldn't seem to find any way to do this.

I can do this in Objective C as follows:

```
- (void) flipAndShow:(UIViewController<IDoFancyFlips>*) controller {
    // implementation
}
```

But I can't find the equivalent declaration in C#.

Comment: `public void FlipAndShow<T>(T controller) where T : UIViewController, DoFancyFlips { ... }` Should do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use generics to accomplish this.  Try the following:

```
public void FlipAndShow<TFancyFlippingController>
       (TFancyFlippingController fancyFlippingController) 
     where TFancyFlippingController : UIViewController, IDoFancyFlips
{
    // implementation
}
```

The `where TFancyFlippingController : UIViewController, IDoFancyFlips` constraint ensures that the argument specified for `TFancyFlippingController` must both inherit from `UIViewController` and implement the `IDoFancyFlips` interface.

Comment: @Rahul I'm sorry to say that you are wrong.  A generic constraint can most certainly be a concrete class name.  Try it for yourself.  I use concrete class constraints all of the time.  I think you meant that a constraint cannot be a sealed class.  That is true.

Comment: @Rahul you probably confusing it with generic restriction against "sealed" classes (which is quite reasonable as you'd never have more than one type and generics is pointless in that case)

Answer (score 0):

Considering that all your specific view controller inherits from base `UIViewController` class

```
public class FancyViewController : UIViewController, DoFancyFlips
{
    // ... methods
}

public class NormalViewController : UIViewController
{
    // ... methods
}
```

you can check at runtime whether the passed instance is of type `DoFancyFlips` and then do the processing further; like

```
    public static void FlipAndShow(UIViewController controller)
    {
        if (!(controller is DoFancyFlips))
            return;

        // implementation
    }
```

Comment: The difference between this and the generic method is that this is a runtime error, the generic method is a compile time error. Its an important distinction I think.

Comment: Yes I know I can do it at run time. I want compile time checking for this.

Comment: @RonBeyer, yes it will be a runtime check but there shouldn't be any error since the `is` operator will just end in true/false and the function will return to caller accordingly.

Comment: I was going to clarify, by error I meant that it would not perform the desired action, not that it would error out (although you could throw an exception where you return to let the developer know they are doing something wrong instead of just returning).